# Поиск самой длинной ветки дерева (List<>)

Tags: c#, .net, list

Есть такие классы

```
    private class Example
    {
        [Description("ThisAaaAtribute")]
        public string aaa { get; set; }
        [Description("ThixXxAtribute")]
        public double xxx { get; set; }
        [Description("ThisBbbClassAtribute")]
        public Example2 bbb { get; set; }
    }

    private class Example2
    {
        [Description("ThisCccAtribute")]
        public Example3 ccc { get; set; }
        [Description("ThiszzzAtribute")]
        public string zzz { get; set; }
        [Description("ThisVvvAtribute")]
        public string vvv { get; set; }
    }

    private class Example3
    {
        [Description("ThisxaSDAtribute")]
        public Example4 asxa { get; set; }
        [Description("ThisxaSDAtribute")]
        public Example4 asdasd { get; set; }
    }

    private class Example4
    {
        [Description("ThisxaSDAtribute")]
        public string qweqweqwe { get; set; }
    }
```

Кодом получаю коллекцию Description, необходимо программно получить коллекцию вложенных List = 4, для List = 3 и тд, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Правильно ли я расшифровал ваш вопрос : имея экземпляр `Example` Вам необходимо получить список значений поля `qweqweqwe`. (не смотря на уровень вложенности промежуточных классов) ?

Comment: @morphey83 мне нужно найти сколько максимально вложенных классов содержится там. Все что выше это как пример. Это все я перевожу в список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не в курсе ваших классов, но, может вам нужно вот такое

```
public static int GetListHeight(List<Table> list)
{
    if (list == null) return 0;
    if (list.Count == 0) return 1;
    return list.Max(l=>GetListHeight(l.Child)) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @Unnamed если это то, что нужно, не забудьте поставить ответу галочку

Answer (score -1):

Вот так сделал поиск на самую длинную ветку дерева, может кто подскажет как сократить код?

```
    public static int GetListHeight(List<Table> list, int index = 1)
    {
        if (list == null) return 0;
        int height = index;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].Child != null)
            {
                int updIndex = index + 1;
                var heightSubList = GetListHeight(list[i].Child, updIndex);
                if (heightSubList > height)
                {
                    height = heightSubList;
                }
            }
        }
        return height;
    }
```

Comment: А что тут сокращать? Получился небольшой метод, который еще и читается более менее.

Comment: @iluxa1810 хотелось бы из передачи в метод убрать int index = 1, что бы он внутри только крутился, а сам метод определения принимал на себя только список

Comment: Ну... можете либо в поле класса вынести, либо сделать вложенную функцию.